# Showing that the $n$-th positive integer that is not a perfect square is $n+\{\sqrt{n}\}$, where $\{\}$ is the "closest integer" function

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Answering a question on sequences which asks to show

> If $a_n$ denotes the $n$-th positive integer that is not a perfect square, then 
>   $$a_n = n + \{ \sqrt n \}$$ 
>   where $\{ x \}$ is the closest integer to the real number $x$.

I argued as follows:

Given a positive integer $n$,  there is some positive integer $m$ such that $$m^2 - m + 1 \le n \le m^2 + m$$

and hence

$$\sqrt { m^2 - m + 1 } \le\sqrt n\le\sqrt{ m^2 + m }$$

Since

$$m -\frac12 < \sqrt{ m^2-m+1 }\,,\,\,\text{and}\;\; \sqrt{m^2 + m} < m + \frac12$$

then $$m - \frac12 < \sqrt n < m + 1/2$$ 
hence  $\sqrt n = m$. By this, 
$$m^2 + 1 \le n + \sqrt n  \le m^2 +2m$$ 
and no integer from $m^2 + 1$ to $m^2 + 2m$, inclusive, is a perfect square.

Now:

> Is the first step (defining the $m$-based interval where $n$ lies) valid?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for all mathematical expressions, not just some of them.

Comment: I edited your post. Please look into it to learn how to write correctly mathematical expressions with MathJaX here.

Comment: I think you meant $\;\lfloor x\rfloor\;$ instead of $\;\{x\}\;$ , otherwise I think the equality fails for $\;a_5=7\;$ , for example...

Comment: @DonAntonio Is this right?  It looks to me like $5+\{\sqrt5\}=5+2=7.$  We have $\sqrt5\approx 2.236,$ so the closest integer is $2.$

Comment: Also for $a_8=11$ we have $8+\{\sqrt8\}=8+\{2.8284271247461903\}=8+3=11$

Comment: @saulspatz The OP **defined** $\;a_n\;$ as the $\;n\,-$ th  natural number that is not a perfect a square. The $\;5\,-$ th such natural is $\;7\;$ , **not** $\;5\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, $a_5=7,$  so according to the OP's formula, we should have $5+\{\sqrt5\}=7,$ shouldn't we?  I'm afraid I don't see your point.

Comment: No point: I only messed at one point between $\;a_n\;$ and $\;n\;$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is certainly valid.  The intervals $[m^2-m+1,m^2+m]$ partition the positive integers.  Note that $$(m+1)^2-(m+1)+1=m^2+m+1.$$

Comment: Great to learn! :) Thanks a lot :)
I've taken that step based on an intuition for a pattern I found; could you please lead me to where I'd learn this partitioning method more formally so I'd  use it more carefully in coming arguments?!

Comment: @HishamAhmed I hadn't seen this before, so far as I recall.  All I did was confirm what you found.

Comment: you we were of great help, thanks a lot! I'll investigate more :)