# Show that if a_ndenotes the $n$th positive integer that is not a perfect square, then $a_n = n+\{\sqrt{n}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, sequence-of-function

Show that if $a_n$denotes the $n$th positive integer that is not a perfect square, then $$a_n = n+\{\sqrt{n}\}$$ where {x} denotes the integer closest to the real number x.

$a_3=5=3+2$

$a_4=6=4+2$

$a_5=7=5+2$

$a_6=8=6+2$

We can notice that $x^2<n+x<(x+1)^2$

Solving this inequality, we get

$x^2-x+\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}<n< x^2+x+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}$

$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}<n<(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}$

But then, I have no idea how to move to the next function which is

$k-\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{n}<k+\frac{1}{2}$

In order to prove that k = {$\sqrt{n}$} and $a_n=n+k=n+\sqrt{n}$.

(I also don't understand why "$k-\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{n}<k+\frac{1}{2}$" indicates that k = {$\sqrt{n}$})

I am self-studying discrete mathematics, and I am stuck with this problem. I need your help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check this:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2800348/42969

Comment: the formula I am familiar with is $a_n=n+\lfloor .5+\sqrt n\rfloor$.  See the [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A000037). I suppose that's an easily confirmed variant.

Comment: @Martin R
I have already checked this, but I don't understand it. That's why I'm posting by myself.

Comment: May be worth noting:  $\{x\}$ commonly denotes the "fractional part of $x$".  Thus $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$.   As far as I am aware there is no universally accepted notation for "closest integer".  I have seen $\lfloor x \rceil$ but it looks odd.  I have also seen $[x]$ but that seems like a terrible idea (as that notation is badly overused).  I guess I would use round$(x)$ for want of anything better.

Comment: Whenever you have some partition of the natural numbers (like in your case squares and non-squares), and you have an explicit enumeration for one part of the partition (in your case the squares $f(n)=n^2$), a tool that allows you to write an explicit enumeration for the other part is [Lambek-Moser theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambek%E2%80%93Moser_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to use [Lambek-Moser theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambek%E2%80%93Moser_theorem). While part of the work is hidden in the proof of the theorem, note that the proof is not difficult. It can be a high-school exercise. My main purpose is to highlight the part of the work that is a pure recipe for problems like this. Namely, we have an increasing function enumerating a subset of the natural numbers and we want to produce an enumeration for the complement.

**Definition:**
Call a pair of non-increasing function $f,g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ a *Galois connection* when
$$f(m)\leq n\iff m\leq g(n)$$
They are like "inverses of each other with respect to inequalities".

**Observation:**
$$
\begin{align}
f(m)&=\min\{n:\ m\leq g(n)\}\\
g(n)&=\max\{m:\ f(m)\leq n\}
\end{align}
$$

**Lambek-Moser theorem:** $f,g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ are a Galois connection if and only if
$$
\begin{align}
A&=\{f(m)+m:\ m\in\mathbb{N}\}\\
B&=\{g(n)+n+1:\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}
\end{align}
$$
partition $\mathbb{N}$.

Let $F(m)=m^2$. We would like to find increasing $G(n)$ such that their ranges partition $\mathbb{N}$. So, define $f(m)=F(m)-m=m^2-m$. The [pronic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number). We just need to compute the "inequality inverse" $g$ of $f$, and that would give $G(n)=g(n)+n+1$, by Lambek-Moser. Already the observation is giving an explicit formula
$$G(n)=\max\{m:\ f(m)\leq n\}+n+1$$
which can be made more explicit, by solving the inequality
$$m^2-m=f(m)\leq n$$
This is quadratic with solution
$$\frac{-\sqrt{4 n + 1} + 1}{2}\leq m\leq\frac{\sqrt{4 n + 1} + 1}{2}$$
So, $g(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{4 n + 1} + 1}{2}\right\rfloor$ and
$$G(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{4 n + 1} + 1}{2}\right\rfloor+n+1=\left\lfloor\sqrt{n+1/4}+1/2\right\rfloor+n+1$$

Recall that $\lfloor x+1/2\rfloor$ gives the closest integer (rounding up in the equal distance case), and that here we count starting from $n=0$, while in your case you start from $n=1$, and you get your formula.